# How to create grid layout items fit to screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

So this is what I'm trying to create.

[image: Sample UI]

**Some background :**

1. The items are fixed (Days of week)
2. The items cannot go to next line and cannot be hor scrollable also. Hence condition to fit them in one line and hence the decision to go with grid layout with fixed span count of 7.

The way I've created the UI is by having a Circle shape drawable set as background of the Textview.

**This is the current result :**

[image: Current result]

**The issues I'm trying to solve are :**

1. Maintaining the circle shape of the drawable for different screen sizes.
2. Maintaining the text size depending on the the circle shape.

Any thoughts / directions towards the solution would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: (Might not be the best solution/suggestion) try to replace textview background attribute with imageview in framelayout with the textview. This way you can keep the original size of the imageview and make your textview font size to fit the image

Answer (score 0):

For these scenarios, where the items in the list are fixed, we preferably don't use dynamic lists like ListView, GridView, RecyclerView. Just create items of LinearLayout with orientation horizontal as a parent having child LinearLayout's with orientation vertical as per your requirement and design layout for Multiple screen layouts with fixed width and padding.

Based on the density or screen size you can create layout files which support multiple screens. [Designing Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) - you can refer this to have additional information regarding this.